# Matrices multiple

Tags: matrices

Given
$$A = \pmatrix{2&-1\cr 3&-2},$$
I'm told to find $A^2$, $A^3$, then deduce $A^{15}$ and $A^{20}$.
I can find the $A^2$ and $A^3$  by normal matrix multiplication 
But how do I deduce $A^{15}$ and $A^{20}$, is there a shorter way?

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if
$$A = \pmatrix{2&-1\cr 3&-2}$$
then
$$A^2 = \pmatrix{1&0\cr 0&1}$$
**the identity matrix**.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin gave you a strong hint.
use the fact that your matrix is involutary  and hence diagonalizable
and then use the fact that $A=P^{-1}DP$.

$A^n=P^{-1}D^nP$ i hope get this??

Comment: What does the P and D represent ?

Comment: P is an invertible matrix and D is a diagonal matrix such that $P^{-1}DP=A$